# Web Link to dashboard and bookmark

Tags: qlikview

Is it possible to create a weblink directly to a Qlikview document, apply a bookmark and open a specific tab?

Ideally not using the internet explorer plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed [here](https://community.qlik.com/thread/53743?tstart=0)

How about:

[http://myserver//QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=DocumentName.qvw&host=Local&sheet=SH01&Bookmark=Document\BM01](http://myserver//QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=DocumentName.qvw&host=Local&sheet=SH01&Bookmark=Document%5CBM01)